# Possible to purchase multiple securities on 1 transaction?

Tags: stocks, fees, online-brokerage

I'm curious, can I purchase multiple securities from my online broker (TD Ameritrade) in 1 transaction? i.e. Purchase ABC and XYZ at same time, but only pay the transaction fee ($9) once.

Comment: If you're trying to reduce your transaction fees, you could try [robinhood.io](https://www.robinhood.io/), which has commission free trading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not generally possible, as each security purchase is booked as a separate order => hence separate transaction.

You can do this through purchasing of a fund, i.e.: purchasing one share of a ETF will get you a relative share of the ETF holdings, but the actual holdings are not up to you then.

Comment: To be clear, an ETF is a single security that is valued by the performance of its underlying holdings.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't, as you would have to have a different order for each security. Usually the bigger the order the more the brokerage you would also pay.

Answer (score 4):

There is such a thing as a buy-write, which is buying a stock and writing a (covered) call simultaneously. But as far as I know brokers charge two commissions, one stock trade and one options trade so you're not going to save on commissions.

Comment: +1 agreed, there are many types of contingency orders one can place. A cascading series of purchases, sales, or a mix of the two, all with their own commission.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yep there are also other kinds of contingency orders, buy-write is the only one that I use

Comment: Thanks. Thats probably getting in over my head, but I will investigate a bit.